# PyPDF2 split pdf keeping original pdf format

Tags: python, pypdf

I am spliting a pdf file by ranges. My code works fine, but the problem is that the new pdf file does not preserve the format of the original pdf.
How can I splita pdf file without losing the original format?

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
#split range
pgi=30 #start
pgf=37 #end

pdf_document = "test.pdf"
pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_document)
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
for page in range(pgi-1,pgf):
    current_page = pdf.getPage(page)
    pdf_writer.addPage(current_page)

with open(f'test-{pgi}-{pgf}.pdf', "wb") as out:
    pdf_writer.write(out)
```

PS: I don't have this problem when I use Adobe or MasterPdfEditor software.

The image below shows the original and new pdf format.
[out format pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IOS4.png)